# IRT modeling for questionnaire develop with a clinical:normal population of 15:1

Tags: survey, item-response-theory

I am trying to apply IRT to a questionnaire for screening purpose -- I have 3000 clinical population but only 200 normal population, would the result useful? The item plots and information function looked okay and the factors resembles those generated by EFA. As IRT is group independent, does this mean my samples distribution would not matter in developing the questionnaires?

(The prevalence of the disease is 1:9, i.e. around 10% prevalence. Therefore for day-to-day use of the questionnaire, the ratio should be 1:9, instead of 15:1... )

Comment: The independence that you allude to only holds, of course, if the assumption of a homogeneous population holds. That means, the groups may differ in the level of the trait/disease, but the item parameters need to be the same (i.e., no DIF (differential item functioning)).